# Angular is not a function Jasmine

Tags: angular

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6ZmTk.png)

Because when I run the tests it tells me that .subscribe is not a function
Everything works for me ok but when doing the unit tests I get that someone to help me

[service.ts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NtvZD.png)
[user.component](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W3yoB.png)

Comment: please no images of code

Comment: how about you post your test code? do not use images for showing source code.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may consider using **HttpTestingModule** and mock the Http response using **HttpTestingController** or, you can create a spy of the service using **createSpyObj** and mock the observable simply by doing this **spyService.getUsers.and.returnValue(of({data: {...}});**

Jasmine Spy Documentation: https://jasmine.github.io/api/edge/Spy.html

HttpTestingController: https://angular.io/api/common/http/testing/HttpTestingController

Answer (score 0):

As per the screenshots you added, you are trying to write unittest for `ListUsersComponent` which is using service as DI to access `getUsers()` method.
**The thumb rule to writing unittest** **cases is we should always mock dependencies when writing unittest cases of a component.**

Here it seems that issue is, you haven't mocked service or you mocked service but didn't mocked `getUsers()` method in such a way that it returns Observable as expected by component.

Mock your service accordingly and it will fix your issue.